# Multilevel inheritance partial class

Tags: c#, class

I need to access referenced classes inside a main class and insert values into the objects. The classes are of partial type.

my code:

```
 public partial class Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object
        {
            public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
            public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
            public string Alpha2_Code { get; set; }
            public string Digit3_Code { get; set; }
            public string CountryName { get; set; }
            public string IBAN_Mandatory { get; set; }
            public As_SenderCountry[] As_SenderCountry { get; set; }
            public As_ReceiverCountry[] As_ReceiverCountry { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class As_SenderCountry
        {
            public string SenderCountry_IsSensitive { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class As_ReceiverCountry
        {
            public string ReceiverCtry_EFTNotAllowed { get; set; }
            public ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY_Item[] ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY_List { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY_Item
        {
            public string ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Task2()
        {
            String xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"../../XML/sample1.xml");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlText)));

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["column"];

            Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object Get_CountryInfo_Resp = new Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object();
            //Get_CountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry;

            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.ReturnCode = dt.Rows[0]["column_Text"].ToString();
            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.ErrorMsg = dt.Rows[1]["column_Text"].ToString();
            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.Alpha2_Code = dt.Rows[2]["column_Text"].ToString();
            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.Digit3_Code = dt.Rows[3]["column_Text"].ToString();
            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.CountryName = dt.Rows[4]["column_Text"].ToString();
            Get_CountryInfo_Resp.IBAN_Mandatory = dt.Rows[5]["column_Text"].ToString();
            //GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry.SenderCountry_IsSensitive
```

I need to Insert `dt.Rows[6]["column_Text"].ToString();` into the `GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry.SenderCountry_IsSensitive` . 
How shall i proceed?
Please help.

Comment: I'd like to note that the fact the classes are `partial` is irrelevant for this question. Partial classes are like normal classes, only split over several files.

Comment: The same is true for inheritance @ThorstenDittmar

Comment: @PatrickHofman True :-)

Comment: I need to add elements from an existing array to the ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY_List array. How shall i proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Since `As_SenderCountry` is an array, it can contain multiple items. You have to assign an array too, not just a single instance.

I would start to create an object, add that to a list and eventually create an array out of it (or change the type to be a list instead of an array). You can also fix-size the array if you know the length already.

```
As_SenderCountry asc = new As_SenderCountry();
asc.SenderCountry_IsSensitive = dt.Rows[6]["column_Text"].ToString();
```

And then:

```
GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry = new As_SenderCountry[] { asc };
```

Or create the list, loop over items and eventually assign it:

```
List<As_SenderCountry> list = new List<As_SenderCountry>();

// some sort of loop
As_SenderCountry asc = new As_SenderCountry();
...

list.Add(asc);
// end loop

GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: I need to add elements from an existing array to the ReceiverCtry_AllowedCCY_List array. How shall i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of the inner class as you would do normally for any other class, and then assign whatever value to the field you need.
First you need to assign the length of the array, then each cell of the array will contain an instance of an object of type (As_SenderCountry ), then you should assign each object the value you need.

```
GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry = new GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry();

GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry[INDEX_HERE].SenderCountry_IsSensitive = dt.Rows[6]["column_Text"].ToString();
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your code, but `As_SenderCountry` and `As_ReceiverCountry` in your `public partial class Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object` are arrays, if I am not reading it wrong.

Therefore, the messy solution, if you know there is only **one sender country**:

```
GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry[0].SenderCountry_IsSensitive = dt.Rows[6]["column_Text"].ToString();
```

Alternatively, you can use Lists - the advantage with lists being, you don't need to know the array size when instantiating. An example with your variables:

```
public partial class Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object
{
      public string ReturnCode { get; set; }
      ...
      public List<As_SenderCountry> As_SenderCountry { get; set; }
      public List<As_ReceiverCountry> As_ReceiverCountry { get; set; }
}
private static void Task2()
{
      String xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"../../XML/sample1.xml");
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlText)));

      DataTable dt = ds.Tables["column"];

      Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object Get_CountryInfo_Resp = new Get_CountryInfo_Resp_object();
      ...
      GetCountryInfo_Resp.As_SenderCountry.SenderCountry_IsSensitive.Add(dt.Rows[6]["column_Text"].ToString());
```

p.s. Your variable and class naming is very messy. I would suggest you to clean that up so that you, as well as the people reading the question can understand it better.

Comment: This will yield a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Yes, since the array is not initialized yet, try adding `As_SenderCountry = new As_SenderCountry[10]` before the line, replacing 10 by whatever amount you will need.